# Drupal7: Change block order programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, block

I want to change the order of my blocks in a region when a user is not logged in. I tried to change the block weight but nothing happened. That's what I tried:

```
function mymodule_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  $blocks['views']['-exp-article-page_knowldg']['weight'] = '-16';
}
```

and

```
function mymodule_block_list_alter(&$blocks) {
  $blocks['131']->weight = -20;
  $blocks['185']->weight = -40;
}
```

I don't want to create a new region and move the block into it, it should work with one region.

Any ideas how to change block order?

Comment: Showing code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Block list alter would do a static change if I'm right.

You can use modules like panels https://www.drupal.org/project/panels or Context https://www.drupal.org/project/context or CSS which can all do the job for you easily.